# How to transform one or more fragments using pageTransformer in VIewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I create an android application using `ViewPager`and `Fragments`. Then I want to transform some fragments between each other using an animation . I select 
`PageTransformer` for this purpose . I use `PageTransformer`with the `ViewPager`.

This my `pageTransformer` code with **MainActivity** class,

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int counterNumber=-1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                    counterNumber=0;
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                    counterNumber=1;
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                    counterNumber=2;
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {
                    counterNumber=3;
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 4) {
                    counterNumber=4;
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

                page.setRotation(position*-100);

            }
        });

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public MyPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: counterNumber=0; return FirstFragment1.newInstance("FirstFragment_1");
                case 1: counterNumber=1;return SecondFragment1.newInstance("SecondFragment_1");
                case 2: counterNumber=2;return ThirdFragment1.newInstance("ThirdFragment_1");
                case 3: counterNumber=3;return FourthFragment1.newInstance("FourthFragment_1");
                case 4: counterNumber=4;return FifthFragment1.newInstance("FifthFragment_1");
                default: return FirstFragment1.newInstance("DefaultFragment_1");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentItem(int which) {
        if(viewPager != null && which >= 0 && which <= 4) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(which);
        }
    }
}
```

But I face to a problem . When I apply this `PageTransformer`, this effects to all fragments . But I want to use this for specific fragments .

How could I achieve it ? Have any ideas ?

Thank you .